# What does the >< badge mean in the VS Code extensions list?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When I connect to a [remote workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) in VS Code, some of my enabled extensions have a badge with a `><` icon. See the ESLint extension for example:

[image]

What does this badge mean and why do I only see it when I connect to a remote workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That badge indicates that the ESLint extension is running on the remote machine. The extension should function the same as if it were running in a normal, local VS Code window.

In order to support remote development, VS Code [distinguishes two classes of extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#architecture-and-extension-types):

- **UI Extensions**: These extensions make contributions to the VS Code user interface and are always run on the user's local machine.
- **Workspace Extensions**: These extensions are run on the same machine as where the workspace itself is located. When you open a local workspace, Workspace Extensions are run on the local machine. When in a remote workspace, Workspace Extensions are run on the remote machine.

The ESLint extension is a workspace extension that is run on the remote machine because it performs file access and other workspace operations. The badge in the extensions view indicates that is running on the remote machine